# PhoneGap Android Some Images are showing up on browser but not in emulator

Tags: android, image, cordova

I am developing android phonegap application. which has around 65 images (~10kb size for each). My application is working as expected on Ripple chrome plugin as well as on Chrome and FF browser. but when I load it on emulator some images are not able to load.

I have attached screenshot for the reference. 
[image: some images are missing.]
[image: working on ripple plugin for chrome]
[image: working on browser]

I tried using the [jQuery preload plugin](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/preload-image-plugins/) but no luck.

Can anyone help me please! Thanks

**EDIT:**
I have tried the same code without any change on iPhone and WindowsPhone7, Images are showing up fine on both the platform.

Comment: I have tried the same code with PhoneGap on iPhone and images are rendering file in iPhone. so looks like its only issue with Android simulator/device.

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual Android device?

Comment: Can it be a file casing issues (lowercase/uppercase mismatches that are missed by the desktop browser) ?

Comment: @jurgemaister Yes, I have tried it on actual device too.. same case.. some images are not loaded.

Comment: @ddewaele, I double check the lower/upper case things.. no issue with that at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an identical copy of the image (../image_**copy1**.png, for example), and swap that code out in lieu of the image location that isn't working.

Sometimes emulator programs freak out with file paths either due to localized caching of data or actual logistical errors in the emulator program itself. Dreamweaver has similar problems, as do a host of other dev/testing suites - local caching of images is not an uncommon problem. You can circumvent this issue sometimes by uploading a copy of the desired file (but not copying it within the program itself) - causing a fresh, noncached upload of it. *This is by no means a "proper" solution*, but it's a quick and dirty workaround for a buggy emu/dev program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the images from an external source, you may need to 'whitelist' the source. Did you add the domain name into the Cordova config file? It is under res/xml/config.xml

```
<access origin="www.example.com" />
```

I know that it is necessary for cross domain AJAX requests but not sure for images, you could give it a try.

Comment: I am loading image from local resource only.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help much.

Emulator acts cranky some times.

I have faced the issue multiple times.

At the best, you can try creating another avd-image... but at least I cannot guaranttee that it will work.

Comment: I have also tested the same code with device (Micromax Tablet) and that is acting the same as Emulator. some images are visible and some are missing.